# Do I need to use google maps api for business

Tags: php, api, google-maps

I'm looking at adding a feature that uses google maps and the google maps api to a social networking site.

However, I am unsure if I need to purchase google maps for business, as the website is subscription based. Users won't be paying specifically for using the maps, but do need to purchase a subscription to use the site.

Does anyone know if I can use the regular google maps api, or do I need to purchase a google maps for business account?

I had a look at the google terms and couldn't really figure out if the above is allowed.

Comment: You should be asking google this question

Comment: I did, but had to wait a while to hear back from them. Thanks for your help, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you need a business account: refer to here: http://www.google.com/enterprise/earthmaps/maps-compare.html

"Reselling services with Google Maps" requires Business Account API access

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I sent an email to google and they confirmed what you said. Bummer!

Comment: Note the mobile exclusion: https://developers.google.com/maps/terms

Answer (score 0):

Improve contact who understands:

[Licensing](http://developers.google.com/maps/licensing)
[Contact](http://services.google.com/enterprise/gme#utm_campaign=en&utm_medium=et&utm_source=devsite-en-compare)

Answer (score 0):

The specific language that Google uses for free access within the free API Limits is that the App must be "Free & publicly available". If the feature you are building with google maps is not "Free & publicly available", then you will need to contact Google's Licensing team to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

You want to have a look at:

Section 9: License Requirements (https://developers.google.com/maps/terms)

You can make the users pay and use the non Maps For Business version if *"your Maps API Implementation is used in a mobile application that is sold for a fee through an online store and is downloadable to a mobile device that can access the online store. "*